# Does Google Cloud Vision API have a feature to extract the age from an image of a face?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have some images of faces which I need to determine the rough age of the faces. Does Google Cloud Vision API have this feature to determine the age? From the documentation, I don't see any such feature. Google Cloud Vision Face Detection seem to be more about detecting expressions and the vertices of the objects in the image which I am not interested in knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this feature is not available, so I have create a feature request and you can follow the progress here [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123614311).

As a workaround, you can get the label "Adult" and the response as "VERY_UNLIKELY", "VERY_LIKELY" etc. Based on that make an roughly estimation of the age.